# How can I USB install Ubuntu 12.04.4 on my Macbook using the 32-bit image?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, mac, system-installation, 32-bit

I've downloaded both the 32 and 64-bit images of Ubuntu 12.04.4 and used the startup disk creator in Ubuntu to create a both a 32 and 64-bit Ubuntu install USB.

However, I am only able to boot from the 64-bit install USB. The 32-bit install USB won't even show when I try to show external devices on boot by holding alt. **The screen is just white.**

I've noticed, that the 64-bit install USB contains an *EFI folder* that the other one is missing. So I tried to play around a bit by copying the *grub and EFI folders* to the 32-bit install USB. **Now** the 32-bit install USB would appear during boot. But when I select it, the kernel fails to load.

#### Can you please help me to make it possible to install 32-bit 12.04.4?

<sup><sup><sup>I have only 2GB of RAM...</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: This question is a little similar and may help:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/433949/what-is-the-recommended-release-of-ubuntu-for-32-bit-intel-based-macs

Answer (score 2):

You are right, Macs only boot using EFI, and Ubuntu 12.04 does only bring EFI support in 64bit edition, but according to this  [german blog post](http://www.bloggerholiker.de/704/mac-ubuntu-von-usb-stick-booten/), you can still do it by carrying out the following steps:

1. Format your flash drive to a FAT file system
2. Download http://www.bloggerholiker.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/ISO-2-USB-for-EFI.zip
3. create a efi folder on the flash
4. create a boot folder inside the efi folder
5. extract the content of the zip into the boot folder
6. rename the 32bit iso to boot.iso and put it in the very same folder
7. reboot your mac and press and hold the ALT key
8. select Boot.efi when prompted

That should do the trick. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, but unfortunately it did not provide a solution. Using this method I am able to successfully boot the 32-bit install USB and completely install Ubuntu afterwards - however, Ubuntu will not boot afterwards. Instead I am greeted with a GRUB message: "Minimal BASH-like line editing..." [Here's a picture.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/98y20wj3l6jntdy/430969.jpg)